# how to include prebuilt shared libraries in apk with eclipse

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, android-ndk

I have a shared library libfoo.so and need to use it in my android app.

My first try was to have in Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(PATH_TO_FOO) -lfoo
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

in my activity, I have:

```
statis
{
    System.loadLibrary("foo");
}
```

This builds correctly, however I noticed that created apk doesnt include libfoo.so (also I see it is not copied to libs/armeabi). I guess for that reason I have UnsatisfiedLinkError when executing my app.

I saw in some other posts that I need to add $(PREBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY), so I add the following to my Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FOO_PATH)/libfoo.so
include $(PREBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But now I am getting the build error:

```
foo: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file.
```

I am sure that the path is correct. Note that the libfoo.so was having origionally the version number at the end, though I had to remove it (and leave only .so) since ndk-build complained.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The include appears to be misspelt:

```
include $(PREBUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

should be

```
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution!! LOCAL_SRC_FILES can not have absolute or relative paths, just the filename. The path must be set in LOCAL_PATH.

So in my case, instead of:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FOO_PATH)/libfoo.so
```

I have now:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(FOO_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.so
```

And this works ok.

Comment: hey.. can you put some light on it. m facing same problem. i am having 3 .so files to be loaded what should i write in .mk file?

Comment: Downvote. LOCAL_SRC_FILES can definitely contain relative paths.

Comment: Can it have absolute paths?

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse, i add a static library by copying the file in the path project/libs/armeabi/ and rebuild the project after cleaning it. This includes the .so in the apk.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (ADT22, Indigo, ndk-r9). The lib gets deleted on build.