# NDK: How to include Prebuilt Shared Library Regardless of Architecture

Tags: android-ndk

I am working on porting Box2D to learn a little more about android porting.

I can get the project compiling and I see the following....

> ls libs/
>
> armeabi        armeabi-v7a

Now I want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927210/how-to-include-prebuilt-shared-libraries-in-apk-with-eclipse) but i don't know how to make it smart enough to choose arch (say I wanted to add x86). How do I include the .so without hard coding the .so path to a spec arch?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This worked...

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := box2D-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../Box2D/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libbox2D.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := box2DHello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,, \
    $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp))
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lm -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := box2D-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: i am facing the same problem but i have only to use the .so file. i have follow your instruction write LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := box2D-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../Box2D/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libbox2D.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/..
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
 but this give error in prebuiltlibaray.mk

Answer (score 18):

Simply define which architectures you would like to support in android.mk and Application.mk as described in the NDK documentation (APPLICATION-MK.html and PREBUILTS.html):

> ### V. ABI Selection of prebuilt binaries:
>
> As said previously, it is crucial to provide a prebuilt shared library
>   that is compatible with the targeted ABI during the build. To do that,
>   check for the value of TARGET_ARCH_ABI, its value will be:
>
> armeabi     => when targeting ARMv5TE or higher CPUs    armeabi-v7a
>   => when targeting ARMv7 or higher CPUs    x86         => when targeting x86 CPUs    mips        => when targeting MIPS CPUs
>
> Note that armeabi-v7a systems can run armeabi binaries just fine.
>
> Here's an example where we provide two versions of a prebuilt library
>   and select which one to copy based on the target ABI:
>
> ```
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> LOCAL_MODULE := foo-prebuilt
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfoo.so
> LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
> include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
> ```
>
> Here. we assume that the prebuilt libraries to copy are under the
>   following directory hierarchy:
>
> ```
> Android.mk            --> the file above
> armeabi/libfoo.so     --> the armeabi prebuilt shared library
> armeabi-v7a/libfoo.so --> the armeabi-v7a prebuilt shared library
> include/foo.h         --> the exported header file
> ```
>
> NOTE: Remember that you don't need to provide an armeabi-v7a prebuilt
>         library, since an armeabi one can easily run on the corresponding
>         devices.

Comment: Looks like you were right after my answer which is pretty much the same. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 4):

**Android NDK official `hello-libs` CMake example**

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/840858984e1bb8a7fab37c1b7c571efbe7d6eb75/hello-libs

The key thing is to pack all versions of the `.so` that you care about, e.g.:

- `distribution/gperf/lib/arm64-v8a/libgperf.so`
- `distribution/gperf/lib/x86_64/libgperf.so`

and then pick the right one on CMake with: `${ANDROID_ABI}`.

I have further explained that example at: [How to link a prebuilt shared Library to an Android NDK project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870435/how-to-link-a-prebuilt-shared-library-to-an-android-ndk-project/47558694#47558694)

Answer (score 3):

Anyone looking for good documentation around any android.mk problems, refer this:

https://github.com/Parrot-Developers/alchemy/blob/master/doc/android-mk.html

I found it very nicely explained in simple words and covering most of scenarios around Android.mk. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

libmath-prebuilt.so is a prebuilt library which has some functions which are used by buyya_read.c. First generate libmath-prebuilt.so using ndk-build and keep in jni folder where buyya_read.c is kept in ur project in elcipse.

```
Android.mk(To generate libbuyya_read.so to use as jni library using prebuilt library)
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE := math-prebuilt
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES = libmath-prebuilt.so
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE    := buyya_read
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := buyya_read.c
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := math-prebuilt
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

buyya_read.c
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_buyya_BuyyaJava_sum(JNIEnv *env,
    jclass thiz, jint a, jint b) {
hello();
int res = add(a, b);
return res;
}

math.c // using this generate libmath-prebuilt.so
#include <stdio.h>
void hello()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
int add(int a, int b)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return a+b;
}

Make file to generate libmath-prebuilt.so
Android.mk
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE    := math-prebuilt
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := math.c
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
    #LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES:=../jni/
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You see the project directory structure in below image. 
[image: Project Dir Structure]