# Build SDL mixer for Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, sdl

I have already build [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) for Android. 
But, unfortunately, SDL_mixer is missing there. So I want to build [SDL mixer](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/).
Problem is: SDL_mixer wants SDL, so how I can include `libsdl.so` and SDL includes to my eclipse SDL_mixer project?

Comment: I have SDL.so and includes. I want to use it to build SDL_mixer. How I should include it in Android.mk file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Android.mk** for SDL_mixer, there is a reference to SDL library:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES = SDL2
```

So, if you build the two libraries *together*, the reference will be fulfilled automatically. Alternatively, you can define SDL2 as [PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172153/ndk-how-to-include-prebuilt-shared-library-regardless-of-architecture).