# How to add a third party C library in android apk?

Tags: android

I have a prebuild third party C library libliveplay.so, I want to add it to apk. I put it under

```
libs/armeabi
libs/armeabi-v7a
```

and my android.mk file is like:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := RtspPlayer
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libliveplay

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

but it can't add the so into apk with this method, could anyone help?

When apk build out, I install it on my device, and runtime error happened:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1064)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load liveplay from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.mrlans.play-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.mrlans.play-2]: findLibrary returned null
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    at com.mrlans.play.MediaActivity.<clinit>(MediaActivity.java:152)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4660):    ... 15 more
```

The error indicated that the so did not include in the apk, it didn't  install into system when apk installed. please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650472/how-do-i-import-a-native-library-so-file-into-eclipse

Go through this question.

Comment: Its already a art of the apk and you don't need to add it manually. Just load it at runtime through your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927210/how-to-include-prebuilt-shared-libraries-in-apk-with-eclipse

Comment: please see my question  updated error. I see your advice thread post, I think it not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include libliveplay as PREBUILT library. Place libliveplay.so in your /jni directory so the structure is as following:

```
Android.mk                 --> the file above
armeabi/libliveplay.so     --> the armeabi prebuilt shared library
armeabi-v7a/libliveplay.so --> the armeabi-v7a prebuilt shared library
```

Then in Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := liveplay
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libliveplay.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := RtspPlayer
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liveplay

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Comment: I have tried your method,  the build out apk didn't include libliveplay.so

Comment: Can you check if the path to libliveplay.so is correct?

Comment: my lib path is under project_path/libs/armeabi/ and project_path/libs/armeabi-v7a/ folder, it's android apk libs folder

Comment: if so then you need to put your libliveplay.so in the jni directory and your path should be like this:

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := liveplay
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libliveplay.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

See my edit for info

Comment: I use you edit mk file, then build using 'mmm -B  package/apps/RtspPlayer', the apk didn't include the library either. So frustrate us.