# can I use a native library .so in android project without NDK?

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I have an android project built in eclipse environment with the Android SDK , now I want to add a prebuilt library **(.so)** to this project , should i use **NDK** to do that?

Comment: yes and i got this error message **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:..**

Comment: now, how did you tried to load it? Where did you put the .so ?

Comment: create a **armeabi** folder in Libs,and define the native method as a public in my activity class. finaly calling the native method

Comment: it more or less correct. Did you call `System.loadLibray("nameoflib")` ?

Comment: yes i did, the same error

Comment: I guess you will need the ndk. Take a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927210/how-to-include-prebuilt-shared-libraries-in-apk-with-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you usually don't need to use the NDK to use a native library (.so file) from Java. You only need it if you want to create/recompile a .so file or if the .so files doesn't provide any method implementation to Java.

From where does come your library ? A .jar or a Java class should at least come with it.

In order to use your .so file from Java, you need to know what Java methods it's defining to define the same as native from your Java code, from the same class from the same package name the .so file is made for.

Comment: yes Java methods names are the same as class name and package name, but i solved it by creating a second package in my project has the same name of the original package of the .so lib, little help from **IDA pro** de-compiler to find the original package name :)

Answer (score 2):

No, just create a `jniLibs` folder on the same level of your `res` and `java` folders, and put the .so files in that.